# Implementing Custom Transitions with GoRouter with Shell routring in Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, flutter-go-router

There is this repository on GitHub (https://github.com/bizz84/nested_navigation_examples), which has been incredibly helpful for understanding nested navigation structures. However, I'm interested in adding a bit more flair to the user experience by implementing custom transitions, like fade-ins or slide-ups, between routes managed by GoRouter.

I've been trying to figure out how to integrate these custom transitions within the context of GoRouter, especially when dealing with nested routes and moving between navigation bar pages, but I haven't found much documentation or examples on how to achieve this seamlessly without disrupting the state management and navigation logic provided by GoRouter.

Has anyone successfully implemented custom transitions with GoRouter in a Flutter app, especially in scenarios involving nested navigation? If so, could you share an example or provide guidance on how to achieve this?